# Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'start'

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to run `AudioKit.start()` in my `viewDidAppear` method but I get the following error:

```
Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'start'
```

My pod file includes:

```
pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.0'
pod 'AudioKit/Core', '~> 4.0'
pod 'AudioKit/UI', '~> 4.0'
```

And I'm importing:

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI
```

I'm on Xcode 12.0.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You didn't mention which version of AudioKit actually got installed, but if its the latest pod, use `AKManager` instead of AudioKit.  If I were you I'd leave the Cocoapods world and use Swift Package manager with AudioKit v5.

Comment: Thanks! That has saved some time for me!